# Twitter Bootstrap form layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML which is loaded dynamically by AJAX:

```
        <h5>Contact Information</h5>
    <hr />            
            <div id="formError" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;" class="alert alert-error"></div>
    <div class="form">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmContactInformation" target="<?php echo Uri::create('ucp/updateContactInformation'); ?>" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="ns" id="ns" style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo \Config::get('security.csrf_token_key');?>" id="<?php echo \Config::get('security.csrf_token_key');?>" value="<?php echo \Security::fetch_token();?>" />

            <small><strong>NOTICE</strong> Any address entered here will not be displayed or made publicly available. It will be used for the sole purpose of notifying you of new listings in your area per your notification settings. Should you choose not to enter your address, geolocation based notifications will be unavailable to you. More information is available in our <a href="<?php echo Uri::create('docs/privacy'); ?>">privacy policy</a>.</small><br/><br/>

            <div class="control-group" id="PF-group-addr1">
                <label class="control-label" for="PF-addr1"><strong>Address 1</strong></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" id="PF-addr1" placeholder="Address 1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" id="PF-group-addr2">
                <label class="control-label" for="PF-addr2"><strong>Address 2</strong></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" id="PF-addr2" placeholder="Address 2">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
                    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder=".span1">
                </div>                     
            <div class="form-actions">
                <span id="loader" style="display:none;"><?php echo Asset::img('loader.gif'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Processing ... please wait</span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="frmSubmit"><strong>Save Changes</strong></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Under the field Address 2, I want to have another row which contains three text fields - city, state, and zip.  Each of these fields should also have a label.  The combined width of the labels and fields should equal the total width of the forms container (I believe it is span8).  On a somewhat related note, any other fields I have (such as Address 1 or Address 2) are automatically sized to take up any remaining space in the row horizontally despite setting various sizes like input-small.  Help on either of these issues would be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzLDt.png

Comment: http://imageshack.us/a/img43/1164/overflowss.png

Answer (score 0):

did you mean you like it to be like this? see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/50/

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="city">
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="zip">
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="code">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't seem to have worked for me.  I am using a custom template for Bootstrap if that makes any difference

Comment: have you seen the fiddle? wont that work on your project? having the same code?

Comment: Yes I looked at the fiddle and it looks exactly how I want it laid out, but placing the code into my project yields a different result ... the 3 fields are stacked vertically with the width of each one equal to the width of the forms container - http://imageshack.us/a/img560/3788/overflowss2.png

Comment: aw maybe its in your template using, or maybe you have conflict with other external sources like CSS